# Quick jQuery Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I get an error like this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`

Firebug says this line is the culprit:

```
if($("emailPost2").valid())
```

Here's all my jQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/raw/master/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function(){      
     $("emailPost2").validate({
        rules: {
            emailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                      }
            }
     }); 
     $('#zonePlus').click(function() {
          $('#zoneNotif').submit();
     });

     $('#searchPost').submit(function(event) {
     if ($(this).find('#searchBox').val() == '') {
          event.preventDefault();
     }
     });
     $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
             source: 'php/searchAC.php'
     });
     $("button, input:submit, input:button, a#jql, input:radio").button();

     $('#emailJQButton').live('click',function() {
        $("#emailModal").dialog('open');
     });

     $('#eb1').live('click',function() {
        $('#emailPost').submit();
        $("#emailModal").dialog('close');
     });

     $('#eb2').live('click',function() {
        if($("emailPost2").valid())
        {
            $('#emailPost2').submit();
            $("#emailModal").dialog('close');
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

valid() should return true if it is valid, but I just get the error I mentioned above instead of any results.

**Edit: Here's the HTML code for the form:**

```
<div id="emailModal">
<form action="php/emailPost.php" method="POST" class="inline" id="emailPost2">
<label name="error"></label>
<input type="text" value="Enter an Email" class="required email" name="emailAddress"     style="display: inline-block;">
<input type="button" value="Email" id="eb2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="passedCoupID" value="1"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like for the form?

Comment: It's just a typo, you left off the hash...  should be `$("#emailPost2")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the problem is simply that you forgot the # in the id selector:

```
$("#emailPost2").valid()
```

(rather than the current `$("emailPost2").valid()`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming
form id="emailPost2"

you need

```
if($("#emailPost2").valid())
```

I wanted to BOLD the **#** but was not allowed inside the brackets, hence I was 15 seconds slower :(

Comment: hehe. early bird catches the worm ^_^